# A regular expression to accept URL path with condition

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression as follows:

```
listing/(.+?)/([^\/.]+)/?(reviews/?(.+?)?/?)?/?$
```

it accepts following URLs:

```
listing/united-states/postname1/

listing/united-states/california/postname2/

listing/united-states/california/chino/postname3/

listing/united-states/california/chino/postname4/reviews/testreview/
```

What I can do in order it does not accept:

```
listing/united-states/california/chino/postname1/reviews/

listing/united-states/california/chino/postname2/add-review/
```

Comment: Your regex does not match your given four strings, unless you remove the first `/` from your regex. Also, what's the rationale behind rejecting last two strings? Do you want to reject strings that contain `chino` anywhere? or something else?

Comment: Sorry for misprint. I need URLs ending with 'reviews/' and 'add-review/' to be not accepted by the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead to reject strings that end with `/reviews/` or `add-review` using this regex,

```
(?!.*/(add-)?reviews?/$)listing/(.+?)/([^\/.]+)/?(reviews/?(.+?)?/?)?/?$
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This negative look ahead will reject strings
                         that end with review or reviews or add-review or add-reviews
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QHV2rh/1)**

However, if you strictly want the strings to be reject that only end with `add-review` or `reviews`, you will have to use this regex,

```
(?!.*/(?:add-review|reviews)/$)listing/(.+?)/([^\/.]+)/?(reviews/?(.+?)?/?)?/?$
```

**[Regex Demo strictly discarding your specified strings](https://regex101.com/r/QHV2rh/2/)**

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I need.

Comment: @shamalli: Please consider upvoting/accepting my answer if it helped and that way you get +2 rep as help others in locating the answer easily.